# Adding a validation step via hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()

Tags: 7, forms

I am trying to add a custom validation function to an existing form. I am using `hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()` to edit the form. I am then adding a new function to the #validation array. When I use `dpm()`  and print out `$form['#validation']` I can see that my function is there. However the validation step is not running. If I `dpm()` in the validation function it is not hit.

```
/**
 *  Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function mymodule_form_mycustomdorm_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    $form['#validate'][] = 'mymodule_test';
    dpm($form['#validate']);       
}

function mymodule_test($form, &$form_state) {
  dpm($form_state);
}
```

Comment: Have you cleared the caches since adding the hook function?

Comment: @Clive first thing I do when something is not working. No joy.

Comment: @DEVARAJJOHNSON Please don't edit questions to modify people's code - it makes it impossible to answer the question. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that "mycustomdorm_form" is right? Is it your FORM_ID?

Answer (score 0):

Hi Bobby you can use custom validate submit handler to deal with this

```
$form['submit']['#validate'][] = 'custom_validate_function'
```

all you have to use is `#validate` in submit handler.

use the same callback function as above with replacing the callback name